# Handlebars inline onclick safe?

Tags: javascript, security, onclick, handlebars.js, xss

I have a handlebars template running client-side that renders variables inside an inline onclick like so:

```
<script id="my-handlebars-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <button onclick="console.log('{{name}}');">Click Me!</button>
</script>
```

The context for this handlebars template is coming from an ajax call. `name` was user input on the sign in screen. My question is could someone launch an xss attack by changing their name to some malicious sequence of characters? For instance if `name` was `);alert('hello` would the handlebars template run the alert? From my testing, it does. This just seems wildly easy to write insecure code.

Here is a jsfiddle with a test. Notice how the alert is run when you click on the link `);alert('hello`.
http://jsfiddle.net/68tme0hr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is could someone launch an xss attack by changing their name to some malicious sequence of characters?

Yes. Handlebars escaping only protects HTML.

If you're already in JS, then you are vulnerable.

There are two basic approaches for dealing with this.

## Escape JavaScript data

Pass the data through `JSON.stringify` before putting it into the JS. The JS engine will then treat it as a literal.

Note that strings will get quotes added for you, do you don't need to do that

```
onclick="console.log({{name_after_json_stringify}});">
```

## Put the data somewhere safer than in the middle of the JS

Such as in a `data-*` attribute

```
onclick="console.log(this.dataset.name);" data-name="{{name}}">
```

---

I recommend the second of these approaches as it is simpler and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes this makes sense. I did this so easily it seems like many people could do this without even knowing. I feel like it should be in the handlebars documentation somewhere?